# java menu not working. i'm not being able to use the key down and up to go through the menu correctly

Tags: java, menu

hi my java menu is not working probably is the keylistener i'm not being able to use the key up and down in case 2 to case 4, how can i fix this?
However, i'm not sure how to modify it to make it working correctly, but i know that probably s the keylistener. Im new in java and i'm trying to do this project pls help

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    
    
    
    BufferedImage backBuffer;
    int FPS = 100;
    int JanelaX = 800;
    int JanelaY = 600;
    private static String[] TeclasPressionadas = new String[256];
    // int FundoX = -250;
    int se=-1;
    int c =1;
    int mf=1;
    InputStream in;
    AudioStream audio;
    
    
    
    
    
    ImageIcon Fundo = new ImageIcon("src/Imagens/fundo.jpg");
    Graphics g,bbg;
    
    
   
    
    
   
        
    
    
    public void desenharGraficos(){
         g = getGraphics();
         bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();
         CriaMenu();
         Acede_Opcoes();
        
        //bbg.drawImage(Fundo.getImage(), FundoX, 0, this);
        

        g.drawImage(backBuffer, 0, 0, this);
        
        }
        
      
    public void CriaMenu()
       {
           Font myFont = new Font("bauhaus 93",Font.BOLD,50);
           bbg.setFont(myFont);
           switch(c)
               
           
           {
               case 1:
                   bbg.setColor(new Color(57, 176, 214));
                   bbg.drawString("Jogar", 300, 210);
                   bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                   bbg.drawString("Scores", 300,270);
                   bbg.drawString("Regras",300, 330);
                   bbg.drawString("Créditos", 300, 390);
                   bbg.drawString("Sair", 300, 450);
                   break;
                   
               case 2:
                   bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                   bbg.drawString("Jogar", 300, 210);
                   bbg.setColor(new Color(57, 176, 214));
                   bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                   bbg.drawString("Scores", 300,270);
                   bbg.drawString("Regras",300, 330);
                   bbg.drawString("Créditos", 300, 390);
                   bbg.drawString("Sair", 300, 450);
                   break;
                   
                case 3:
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Jogar", 300, 210);
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Scores", 300,270);
                    bbg.setColor(new Color(57, 176, 214));
                    bbg.drawString("Regras",300, 330);
                    bbg.drawString("Créditos", 300, 390);
                    bbg.drawString("Sair", 300, 450);
                   
                case 4:
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Jogar", 300, 210);
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Scores", 300,270);
                    bbg.drawString("Regras",300, 330);
                    bbg.setColor(new Color(57, 176, 214));
                    bbg.drawString("Créditos", 300, 390);
                    bbg.drawString("Sair", 300, 450);
                    
                case 5:
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Jogar", 300, 210);
                    bbg.setColor(Color.orange);
                    bbg.drawString("Scores", 300,270);
                    bbg.drawString("Regras",300, 330);
                    bbg.drawString("Créditos", 300, 390);
                    bbg.setColor(new Color(57, 176, 214));
                    bbg.drawString("Sair", 300, 450);
          
          
           }
       
           
           }
           
           public void Acede_Opcoes() 
           {
               switch(se)
               {
                   case 1:
                       this.dispose();
                       Game jogo = new Game();
                       jogo.run();
                       break;
                       
                   case 2:
                       this.dispose();
                       //Scores s = new Scores();
                       //s.run();
                       break;
                       
                   case 3:
                      this.dispose();
                      //Regras regras = new Regras8);
                      //regras.run
                      break;
                   case 4:
                       this.dispose();
                        //Creditos creditos = new Creditos();
                        //Creditos.run();
                        break;
                   case 5:
                       System.exit(0);
                       break;
                       
                   
                       
                       
               }
                   

        
         
        
        
    }
    
    public void Inicializar(){
        setTitle("Fruit Cutter");
        setSize(JanelaX, JanelaY);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        backBuffer = new BufferedImage(JanelaX, JanelaY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        addKeyListener(this);
   
        
        
        Arrays.fill(TeclasPressionadas, "");
       
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    
    public void run(){
        Inicializar();
        while (true){            
            desenharGraficos();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000/FPS);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Thred Interrompida!");}}
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.run();
        
    }
    //Problem probably is here
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            c++;
            if(c>5)
            {
                c=1;
                
            }
            
            if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                c--;
                if(c<1)
                {
    
            c=5;
        }
                
                if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    se=c;
                }
                }
            }
}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        if(!TeclasPressionadas[e.getKeyCode()].equals("")){
            TeclasPressionadas[e.getKeyCode()] = "";}}
}
```

Comment: `g = getGraphics();` - No.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more information about how painting works in Swing and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for how you should work with it - this is going to be even more complicated by the fact that you've extended directly from `JFrame`, which is a composite component (it has a number of child components displayed on top of it)

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`s, they are notorious, instead make use of [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

`g = getGraphics();` is not how custom painting works see [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for more information about how painting works in Swing and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for how you should work with it.

Because you've also extended from `JFrame` (which is generally considered a bad idea), you will end up with additional painting issues, as `JFrame` is a composite component (ie, it has other child components laid out on top of it)

[image]

*From [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)*

`BufferedImage backBuffer;` is unnecessary if you use Swing correctly, as Swing is double buffered by default.

`ImageIcon Fundo = new ImageIcon("src/Imagens/fundo.jpg");` is going to cause you no end of issues when you export the project, as `src` won't exist.  Never reference `src` within your code.

`ImageIcon` is also a poor choice, as it will fail silently, instead, prefer [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead.

Since the image is stored within the context of the source files, this will become an "embedded resource", meaning you can no longer reference it as a file (which is another issue with using `ImageIcon` the way you are), instead, you will need to use `Class#getResource`

However, because `ImageIO.read` does throw an exception, you'll have to load the image within the constructor (or some other method), for example...

```
private BufferedImage fundo;

public Game() throws IOException {
    fundo = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Imagens/fundo.jpg"));
```

So, for a simple menu, you don't need a run loop, you're really not doing that much work, just let the system do it for you.

You should take the time to also have a look at:

- [Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)
- [Single Responsibility Principle](https://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)
- [Observer Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)
- [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)
- [Dependency Injection](https://stackify.com/dependency-injection/); [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20dependency%20injection,leading%20to%20loosely%20coupled%20programs.)

All of these concepts will help you build a better solution, isolating functionality and decoupling your code.

I would start with a dedicated "menu component".

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
                menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Jogar", Color.BLACK, new Color(57, 176, 214)));
                menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Scores", Color.BLACK, new Color(57, 176, 214)));
                menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Regras", Color.BLACK, new Color(57, 176, 214)));
                menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Créditos", Color.BLACK, new Color(57, 176, 214)));
                menuItems.add(new MenuItem("Sair", Color.BLACK, new Color(57, 176, 214)));
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MenuPane(menuItems));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuItem {
        private String text;
        private Color textColor;
        private Color backgroundColor;

        public MenuItem(String text, Color textColor, Color backgroundColor) {
            this.text = text;
            this.textColor = textColor;
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public Color getTextColor() {
            return textColor;
        }

        public Color getBackgroundColor() {
            return backgroundColor;
        }                
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        protected enum Direction {
            UP, DOWN;
        }

        private List<MenuItem> menuItems;
        private Color selectedTextColor = Color.WHITE;
        private Color selectedBackgroundColor = Color.ORANGE;

        private int selectedItemIndex = 0;

        private int buttonWidth = 0;
        private int totalButtonHeight = 0;

        private BufferedImage fundo;

        public MenuPane(List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
            this.menuItems = menuItems;

            for (MenuItem menuItem : menuItems) {
                FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
                buttonWidth = Math.max(fm.stringWidth(menuItem.getText()) + 8, buttonWidth);
                totalButtonHeight += (fm.getHeight() + 8);
            }

            totalButtonHeight += (menuItems.size() - 1) * 4;

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "Pressed.up");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "Pressed.down");

            MenuInputAction.Observer observer = new MenuInputAction.Observer() {
                @Override
                public void menuDidNavigate(Direction direction) {
                    switch (direction) {
                        case UP: 
                            selectedItemIndex--;
                            break;
                        case DOWN: 
                            selectedItemIndex++;
                            break;
                    }
                    int count = getMenuItems().size() - 1;
                    if (selectedItemIndex < 0) {
                        selectedItemIndex = count;
                    } else if (selectedItemIndex > count) {
                        selectedItemIndex = 0;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            };

            am.put("Pressed.up", new MenuInputAction(Direction.UP, observer));
            am.put("Pressed.down", new MenuInputAction(Direction.DOWN, observer));
        }

        public Color getSelectedBackgroundColor() {
            return selectedBackgroundColor;
        }

        public Color getSelectedTextColor() {
            return selectedTextColor;
        }

        public void setSelectedBackgroundColor(Color selectedBackgroundColor) {
            this.selectedBackgroundColor = selectedBackgroundColor;
            repaint();
        }

        public void setSelectedTextColor(Color selectedTextColor) {
            this.selectedTextColor = selectedTextColor;
            repaint();
        }

        protected int getButtonWidth() {
            return buttonWidth;
        }

        protected int getTotalButtonHeight() {
            return totalButtonHeight;
        }

        public List<MenuItem> getMenuItems() {
            return menuItems;
        }

        public int getSelectedItemIndex() {
            return selectedItemIndex;
        }

        public MenuItem getSelectedMenuItem() {
            int index = getSelectedItemIndex();
            List<MenuItem> menuItems = getMenuItems();
            if (index >= 0 && index < menuItems.size()) {
                return menuItems.get(index);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(getButtonWidth() + 8, getTotalButtonHeight() + 8);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            int x = (getWidth() - getButtonWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - getTotalButtonHeight()) / 2;

            int buttonWidth = getButtonWidth();
            int buttonHeight = fm.getHeight() + 8;

            MenuItem selectedItem = getSelectedMenuItem();
            for (MenuItem menuItem : menuItems) {
                paintButton(g2d, menuItem, x, y, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, menuItem == selectedItem);
                y += buttonHeight + 4;
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void paintButton(Graphics2D g2d, MenuItem menuItem, int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean isSelected) {
            Color backgroundColor = menuItem.getBackgroundColor();
            Color textColor = menuItem.getTextColor();
            if (isSelected) {
                backgroundColor = getSelectedBackgroundColor();
                textColor = getSelectedTextColor();
            }

            g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

            int textX = x + ((width - fm.stringWidth(menuItem.getText())) / 2);
            int textY = y + ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

            g2d.setColor(textColor);
            g2d.drawString(menuItem.getText(), textX, textY);
        }

        protected class MenuInputAction extends AbstractAction {
            protected interface Observer {
                public void menuDidNavigate(Direction direction);
            }

            private Direction direction;
            private Observer observer;

            public MenuInputAction(Direction direction, Observer observer) {
                this.direction = direction;
                this.observer = observer;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                observer.menuDidNavigate(direction);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, what's missing?  A trigger callback, how does the caller know when a menu item is selected?

Well, this is up to you now. I would...

- Add an observer callback to notify the caller that some menu item has been selected/actioned
- Add a key binding for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and a `MouseListener` to detect when the user clicks an item - however, this is going to present you with issues, as you need to dynamically calculate the button bounds (I might consider doing this up-front). You can do basic collision detection using [`Rectangle#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains(int,int))